# Change App name in »exit« help text of vorpal app

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, vorpal.js

When entering help vorpal says:

```
exit [options]   Exits instance of Vorpal.
```

Is it possible to override the word Vorpal? Because users might not know what Vorpal is and might be confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`find`](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/api-|-vorpal#vorpalfindstring) method to find the existing `exit` command, and then use the [`description`](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal/wiki/API-|-vorpal.command#commanddescriptionstring) method to edit its help description:

```
const exit = vorpal.find('exit');
if (exit) {
  exit.description('My custom help description');
}
```